# How do I remove the first element in a list without using the del/pop/splicing/index/remove/find methods?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming and I'm having some trouble with my code. I need to remove the first element in a list without using any of the mentioned methods. What I have so far:

```
user_string = str(input("Enter a one-character string"))
user_string = user_string.lower()
user_list = [1,2,3]

def choiceN(user_list):      #goes to this function if the user enters n as user_string
temp_list = []
for i in range(1, len(user_list)):
    temp_list.append(user_list[i])
    return temp_list
```

I don't see where this is going wrong. As I'm new to programming, any explanations would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just return the list from _outside_ the loop (correct your indentation, it's all wrong)

Comment: `return user_list[1:]`?  Oh wait, I think your title said you can't do this?  Why can't you?  Is this some sort  of learning exercise?  Why would you purposefully not use the tools as designed?

Comment: Hi, thanks for picking up on the indentation. I've corrected this. This now returns an empty list instead of deleting the first element,1, in the list. I need it to just delete the first element but return the others. Thank you.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, splicing isn't allowed, unfortunately.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yes, it's a learning exercise and for some reason we're not allowed to use these methods.

Comment: Your code seems to work once the formatting/indentation is fixed.

Comment: It returns an empty list, unfortunately. I would like it to return all of the list but just not the first element. So it would remove index [0] but return the other elements.

Comment: How are you calling `choiceN`?  It seems to work for me: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#ZY/BasMwDIbvfoqf7mJDVuh2K@y4616ghGFcJRFksmcr7PEzJy1pxnSxJX8/nzVPhfJn0czS4w31YlnSpPbwLkoZHlHoOQw@@7D0N/LgnPkb3HXHMf5Qtndi5KL1/XJqXprX1pgrdQhD5EAfdgPcGWs99ZEKNEIHLugmCcpRwF0d0OoALd8qEPiyl5olrvSVNmG7jrqYwWBB9tKTPTUYSXZidza415Y@@pRIrg/qwq1bsUw6ZXmQxqQq17rr7fy/mJvn718 "Python 3 – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of the list for only the 2nd element to last element and delete the first list.

Comment: Would this work if the user could also modify the list with another function? E.g. if they could add elements as the list originally starts off as empty. I've just placed elements in there to see what's happening.

Comment: It depends on the way you write your code. Write code to handle when list would get deleted and when new list would get created so that there are no exceptions. Possible.

Comment: The program needs to return the original list, so I've added `temp_list = user_list` just above and changed it to return user_list. So I can't delete the first list.

Comment: so do you only want to create and modify copy of the list ? keep original list as a reference? create pointer to original list value so that you don't modify the original, only the pointer value? not quite sure what you're trying to do

Comment: I want to make the program so that when the user enters n for `user_string`, the function `ChoiceN(user_list):` should create a temporary list and remove the index [0] from the list. The list could change based another function I have, so the list could be [4,5,6] but it should still remove index [0]. After that, it should change the temporary list back into `user_list` and then return `user_list`. Sorry for the long explanation, just tried to make it clear.

Comment: so it sounds like keep the initial list as a reference. only modify the copy as your working list. at the end, copy the original list back into your working list, or return your original list again. should give you what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. However, the code I have above attempts to do this and isn't working for some reason.

Comment: I've figured it out - I had to make 'user_list' a global variable and return the list outside of the for loop.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yay! Happy coding!